# Develop Simple OS under Mac OS X, how to build the boot img from the Mach-O?

Tags: operating-system

I am writing a simple OS under Mac OS X environment. I can build a simple bootloader by nasm. when i develop the more part by C language, i should build them together. The GCC of Mac OS X will compile a Mach-O output format. I want to know how to cat the instruction part of the output object, and link it together with the nasm part.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bigger problem which you aren't seeing.

GCC does not generate 16-bit x86 code, only 32-bit or 64-bit. x86 PC bootloaders start execution in the real addressing mode, which is a 16-bit mode for 16-bit code only.

So, even if you manage to link together the C code compiled with gcc and the assembly code compiled with NASM, you won't be able to execute the C code part (any 32-bit code part for that matter) until after you've switched into the 32-bit protected mode, which is not a very easy thing to do.

And you don't want to switch into protected mode in the 512-byte-long boot sector either. BIOS functions cannot be used in protected mode. If you switch too early, you won't be able to load any more stuff from the disk.

The most practical strategy is to split the bootloader into several parts. The 512-byte-long bootsector would load the next part(s) using the BIOS disk I/O functions. And those other parts will either contain the whole OS, or enough code that would load the rest of the OS either by using the same BIOS I/O functions or by using its own disk driver(s) in the real or protected mode.

So, you are doomed to writing 16-bit code in assembly language by hand for the bootsector, no C, no 32-bit.

You can, however, use other C compilers capable of producing 16-bit x86 code for the other parts of the bootloader. There are at least two of such compilers freely available online:

- Turbo C++ 1.01 (runs only in DOS, Windows XP or below, VMs with DOS/Windows, e.g. DosBox)
- Open Watcom C/C++ 1.9 (runs in DOS, Windows and probably Linux)

Comment: thank you. I have finished the boot part, and switch to the protect-mode. i can run a simple os with two tasks. but the all code is assembly language by nasm. i have moved to 32-bit mode. the question is, i want to link the head.s with some c code. thanks.

Comment: Make a normal ELF binary or whatever the compiler can produce. Then either make a loader for that format, or post-process it with other tools, e.g. `objdump`.

Comment: Alternatively, check if your linker supports a flat binary output format. But, even though that may look like a great simplification, it's actually an oversimplification, because at some point you will need to distinguish code areas from data areas, read-only areas from writable areas, executable from non-executable, etc. And you may want to support relocatable binaries. All of that implies that the binary need to contain some information about itself inside.

Comment: thanks. i have seen some materials about elf, but because of my mac os system, my output is Mach-O format, which is more complicate than ELF.  i want to get some materials about Mach-O to raw binary code.